# SP 2013 not starting User Profile Synchronization Service

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, user-profile, user-profile-service

New offline installation, no changes were made to the server configuration, error when starting User Profile Synchronization Service, log Windows:

> 6398: Category timer ***The Execute method of job definition
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.LMTRepopulationJob (ID
>   bb175d94-b925-4567-b3d6-bbfccbd3fc46) threw an exception. More
>   information is included below.
>
> Unexpected exception in FeedCacheService.IsRepopulationNeeded:
>   Connection to the server terminated,check if the cache host(s) is
>   running .

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the level of rights of your system account which is set for the service to the SharePoint_Config database, if equals 'public' It will not be enough.